Is it rude to ask my PhD student to give a daily report?
I normally have weekly meetings with my PhD students. However, when I saw one student, I noticed that she simply did a few easy things before to the appointment. During the conversation, I felt her work was even worse quality than my two summer interns.
I'm thinking of requiring her to give me daily updates, regardless of what she did.
I have five PhD students; if I just ask her to do this, would it appear like I am targeting her? Is there a better way to handle this? Any comments or suggestions?
P.S. I don't exactly record their working hours; nevertheless, in most of the weekly meetings with other students, I believe the quality and quantity of work, as well as the questions and difficulties expressed, are fair.
P.P.S.

If she has not improved her development, she may not be able to graduate.
I'm not certain of the specific explanation behind this. If I ordered her this week to complete job A with three subtasks A1, A2, and A3 (which, in my opinion, is a realistic weekly task), she may report that she has completed A1 at the next week's meeting.
When I asked about A2-3, she just said that she is learning. But as I further ask what she is learning she merely told me she was learning. But when I ask her about what she's learning, what gets her stuck, and so on. She just cannot explain.

However, when the assignments were urgent, I would ask her to finish A1 on Monday, A2 on Wednesday, and A3 on Friday, and by checking in on her work on a daily basis, she was able to complete them. That is why I am thinking I should start setting deadlines for each work and asking for progress on a daily basis.
To be honest, I prefer not to do it. As for the other pupils, either I tell him/her about A1, A2, and A3, or they will submit the findings next week. OR I'll simply say A, and they'll figure out A1-A3 and proceed. Some may offer B and C.
P.P.P.S.
Thank you all of the comments and suggestions. I think I will start from telling her she may not be able to graduate given the current performance, and asking progress/update more frequently, such as everyday/every two days. I am not good at micromanaging, but some students may need. In this case, the tasks/goals maybe more structured.

Do you think that she needs more meetings or more structured goals? I would keep the same meeting frequency, but define with her achievable goals/tasks to be completed from one week to another. Hopefully, she will learn how to organise herself and seek her own research directions after a while. On top you can give her the option to seek your advise before the weekly meeting, if she feels stuck.

Many people (not just students) need to learn how to be productive. It isn’t an intrinsic skill. I suspect that there are resources at your institution to help.

"However for one student I can clear tell that she basically only do some simple things before the meeting, when I met her." Have you communicated this to her? If not, that should probably be your first step.

Are you serious about this question? Are you just complaining about your student here?

@TheDoctor At least just setting goals is not useful. but breaking the task to subtasks and ask frequently seems work.

@AdamPřenosil I did not say too explicitly, but I think need to be explicit.

@scientist No. I don't think she can graduate, based on the first year performance, if nothing change. For 1-2 times there were urgent tasks and I asked progress update daily for a week, she seems perform similarly to my other students.

@Trunk it is statistics, data analysis and modeling. I set weekly meeting doesn't mean they can only talk to me in that meeting. Some of them may have more questions and like more communications, some have less and prefer learn themselves and only told me the difficulty in weekly meeting. For the other 4 I think their progress are reasonable and they can graduate. So I did not change anything and also they did not complain.

it is individual. I never interrupt and let her finish, but she speak very few. I usually need to ask questions. I set the meeting 30 mins. Usually we finished in 10-15 mins.

There are some people who do need micromanagement at the beginning. However, this should go down over time at the level of a PhD. If the micromanagement helps the student, it is acceptable to start with it and ease it off. If it keeps going, however, the question is whether the student is PhD material. This would be a matter for how this is regarded in your department. Some places have intermediate steps to monitor PhD progress, this is the moment where you can make decisions without the sunk cost of a PhD (for both, student and supervisor). If you do not have that, it is more difficult.

On you comment " if I just ask her to do this, would it appear like I am targeting her" - well you are just targeting her - if I were one of your other students I would find it quite annoying - and if I knew the reason it would be particularly problematic as you're creating work for everyone because one person isn't performing.

No matter what you do , if there is nothing to praise, just don't \try to\ humiliate her in from of others

In your example above, if you give her task A and she only achieved task A1 next meeting, is she still able to come up with tasks A2 and A3 on her own?

Aside from what people have mentioned, I would also consider the impact of daily meetings on your time and mental resources. While it might be perceived that you're targeting a student, it could also go the other way- that the lab feels you have a favourite who gets all the resources and a "gift" PhD without putting in the effort to become an independent researcher.

What I've learned in 19 years being a professor is that every one of my students is/was different and that the same approach does not work for everyone. So you find ways to individualize what you do with them. This may include having meetings more/less often than for others.
That said, before you make decisions, have a conversation with the student. Tell her what you observe, what your thought process is, and how you think you want to tailor your approach to her. Come to a solution together with her, instead of making one for her. Ask her whether her work is done just before the meeting and whether she thinks that she would do better work if she met with you daily.

Talking with her is definitely the way to go. A compromise somewhere between daily meetings/reports and only meeting once a week could be asking her to keep a note of what she worked on each day so she can talk you through what she did that week in each meeting. The first few months of my PhD I wrote down what I did in my diary each day for my own benefit because otherwise I got to the end of the week and felt like I hadn't done anything.

In some of my classes, I ask students to keep a diary in the same way as experimental scientists often keep lab books. This, too, is a great strategy to ensure continuous progress. In these classes, students share the diary (=a google doc) with me, and I can give feedback on a daily basis, or whenever I have time to look at them.

Have your student drive her own research progress
It is sensible to adjust supervision arrangements to individual students, but at tertiary level it is also best if the student drives their own progress rather than being encumbered by busywork to allow the supervisor to police their progress.  There are several problems with asking for daily reports of progress, including the fact that they: (1) detract from time available for substantive research progress; (2) discourage modes of research progress that involve general reflection, etc., where substantive progress is not evident on a daily basis; and (3) put the supervisor in the role of "policeman" for research progress.  It is generally much better for a supervisor to focus on research outcomes in terms of milestones, etc., than to try to track progress each day.
An alternative method that might be useful here is to assist your student to set her own research schedule and give her accountability to drive progress.  If you have not already done so, you should have your student create a Gantt chart setting out her research and publication plan, and ensure that this plan is sufficient to advance her research to completion within the program time, with proper milestones, etc.  Instill her with the knowledge that she will be accountable for driving her own research progress (but can ask for your support when needed) and that if she does not make sufficient progress then she will be in danger of missing milestones and ultimately failing to complete her program.  Use the "empower and trust" model where you give the student a realistic understanding of her options and their consequences, and then let her choose her own pathway and consequent outcome.  Keep her informed if you perceive a lack of progress and offer support where needed, but don't take on the role of policeman.
Your existing weekly meetings should include discussion to keep track of progress over the periods between these milestones to see how work is progressing, but the student should be responsible for driving progress.  Have a realistic discussion with your student about progress towards research milestones and point out where she appears to be falling behind.

I think a Gantt chart is going to be an annoying waste of time at this stage.

even if the progress may make the student not getting PhD, or need 1-2 more years?

A brief remark on the somewhat condescendingly toned comments of @Trunk and Tom. I am using a Gantt chart for my Ph.D. work. It's an amazing tool: it helps me to, first, understand how exactly I spend my time, second, analyze the way I work and adjust it to increase efficiency, third, stay on the path towards major deadlines. I would recommend it to any Ph.D. student at any stage of the Ph.D. work.

+1 on Gantt chart. I find this to be the best way to encourage discipline and effectiveness.

Contrary to the sceptical comments here, a Gantt chart is a great research tool for a PhD candidature, even for such basic things as progression to fixed program milestones.  A typical PhD program has candidature milestones that a student needs to progress and prepare for, and a Gantt chart can incorporate these and the backward preparatory tasks for them.  Scheduling research is harder, but it can still be useful to set expectations like how long in the candidature it will take to set the research question, do the literature review, etc.  Falling behind is then more evident.

Trunk, so then we provide freedom and possibly then they fail their research program but remain undemeaned. Doesn't some creativity, direction of attack and any preliminary stage results positive or negative steering the direction need to appear.

The thing is, a PhD candidature is something with a limited known duration (subject to some possible extension periods), so whether or not it is ideal to the creative process to work under such a time restriction, that is what the university requires of the student.  Because the candidature is for a limited duration, with known milestones, there are known durations to get to points in the research process.

Accountability can be achieved by setting up a task tracker. It allows setting up the tasks, deadlines, ETAs, communicates the progress, while also relieving one from writing a formal report. Then the student and the advisor can agree that a lack of progress marked in the task tracker in, say, three days, automatically leads to a conversation about the difficulties. This seems like a reasonable midpoint.

Gantt charts are useful for getting students to think about what needs to be done, breaking it up into steps, thinking about deliverables and deadline.  The mistake is thinking you will stick to them, or trying to do so, especially for a research project.  They are also useful for recording how you used your time after the project.

Let's state the obvious: for some researchers, Gantt charts work amazingly. For others, however, especially those who work in bursts or topics with unclear strategy, it is a perfect way of killing creativity, fostering guilt, and learning how to self-decept into confounding planning with execution. I do not think that's OP's student case here, but I do not feel that a Gantt chart will help here, either.

Given the discussion around Gantt charts, an alternative is an appropriately adapted Scrum implementation with a prioritized backlog. Additionally, a visible Scrum board (physical or digital) lets the advisor know exactly how the work is going; they just have to see the Scrum board. The Scrum board can entirely replace a daily report. Please note Scrum is not only used in corporations or software; researchers also use it.

In general when a subordinate fails to meet expectations you are in conflict. This is OK in the sense that it happens. This type of conflict resolution is quite simple to solve by following these steps:

Meet with your subordinate/student/intern/etc. in a relaxed environment, potentially over coffee. Start with all the goods she has (smart, diligent, whatever you can find) this whole process creates empathy and reduces the feeling of being attacked.
In casual talk, ask how things are going at home, how she generally feels, etc. Maybe she is troubled or depressed. Students can easily get overwhelmed due to immigration, inability to handle time, family issues, etc.
If something is wrong with her, evaluate wether you are able to do something about it and offer your help. If not, ignore this step.
Then, clearly and shortly express that you "believe" that she is falling short of your expectations. Immediately admit that "believing" something does not make it true, so to be fair, tell her that you are going to evaluate her performance closely in the following days.
To this end you will negotiate (not impose) a reasonable work plan with her, including expected milestones and goals, and will follow her in the following (15 days to 3 months), taking into consideration the potential personal complications learned in step 3 (a feasible, tractable and reasonable plan is very important because is the difference between leadership and harassment). Daily progress checks maybe in order if the problem is that the student gets overwhelmed by self-management for example.
Evaluate her performance improvement taking into consideration her personal circumstances.
If she improves, then stop.
If she does not improve express the potential complications that can arise from her failing to improve (not graduating/not being recommended for further research/not being recommended for graduation, etc.) and put her in a final performance evaluation plan.
If she still does not improve, consider terminating her.

Remarks:

This process is best done by an informal committee of your peers. While you will lead the process, it is always good to have a second opinion to your own to keep the process objective, especially during steps 3 and 6.
In general when a subordinate fails to meet expectations you are in conflict. This is OK in the sense that it happens. As a Ph.D. professor, you are in a leadership position, and the nature of the leader can be a nature of conflict. People come to work bounded by mission, not friendship. Your student mission is to graduate, and your mission is to steer your students on the right path, not be their BFF. Not everybody has to like you.
Cultural differences can create communication barriers. When I was a Ph.D. student I was unable to understand orders from my professor because he came from a high-context culture (such as France, Japan, Korea) and I came from a low-context culture (such as USA, Latin America, Germany).


A PhD student is not a "subordinate" in many places. That's the problem.

Thanks. useful concept about high.low context culture.

@Dilworth A PhD student is a subordinate, as they are dependent on their advisors judgement and steering. Without the consent of the advisor they cannot finish their dissertation. They might be independent in the form of not receiving direct orders.

@usr1234567 I must add not just advisor but also committee, and department/university standard.

@usr1234567 The US is not the entire world, right?

@usr1234567, hence I said explicitly "in many places". I repeat: a PhD student is not a subordinate of their advisor in many places, they can finish without their advisor's consent, and they are formally independent of their advisor's judgment.

I think an issue here is that your expectations of her are not getting conveyed - if you do not convey to her that she is not performing up to the expectations set by her PhD program, she doesn't have sufficient opportunity to correct it. Have a monthly (non-technical) feedback meeting with her (and all your other students as well, individually), where both you and your students can tell each other what the goals and expectations are, and what is and isn't working.
Some students need more micromanaging and/or hand-holding, while for some others, their performance would decrease in the long term if micromanaged. By the end of the third year, the student should not need micromanaging, but in the first couple of years, they may. Such expectations should be conveyed - that you're asking for daily updates now, but would like to ween her off of it eventually.
As an alternative, having a clearly outlined project and its milestones can be used. Progress need not be evaluated on a daily or a weekly basis, but whether the milestones of the project are being met in a reasonably timely manner or not. This would require you to work in a goal-oriented manner, rather than a task-oriented manner. As a rule of thumb, a goal would be any target you're looking to achieve in 3-9 month, anything longer would start looking more like a vision. The milestones of the goal can be reasonably clearly defined, either by you, or by your student. A milestone would still need to be broken down into tasks, but it is better that that is driven by your student and not by you, so that she has a sense of ownership about the work and feels sufficiently motivated to do it. In a purely task-oriented environment, a student will find it hard to get a sense of what's going on and may lose interest after a few months.
Also, one has to be mindful that work does not happen at a steady rate. Sometimes, the student might be spending her time learning some tools necessary to do the work, or just thinking, planning, and reading literature. Such activities cannot be done in an environment where daily update on progress is expected.

First thought is that is seems overambitious. Consider how much time is spent on producing the report versus how much time is spent on research. I am not sure what a daily report would reveal. It is clearly a case where the student feels forced to produce unimportant steps to report rather than anything of real importance.
Since the progression of a student depends on the students personality and also the character of the research being conducted, the optimal reporting interval must take external conditions into account. If the progress depends on laboratory experiments, daily reports may be reasonable but in the end the anticipated progress must be considered. In my opinion, I would expect slower progress early in the progress, speeding up as the thesis project progresses through time. That said, the progression will highly depend on the project and the personality pf the student. Hence, the expectation on progression reports should be adapted to reasonable  time frames depending on the character of the project and the personal characteristics of the student.
The progress of a PhD project may not be easily forecast since it depends on many individual factors as well as field dependent, as well as local, expectations.

Thanks. So I think instead of report, I think will start to add deadline and more checking on progress

A 10 min email every day before leaving the lab? Sounds ok to me.

I think (partly @usr1234567) the noun "report" isn't a helpful way to think of it.  "A daily update" might be better.  A "report"  carries connotations of a more formal piece of work

Actually, I believe that this is a red flag for a PhD, and given the other information about the student, I think it would be better to have a serious talk about leaving academia.
I saw people trying to get a PhD for five, even seven years, and then leaving university without it. And even if you barely pass your PhD, you need to leave academia anyway.
On the other hand, from my professional experience outside university, I know quite some people who do a decent job if you give them short, concrete tasks, but failing at anything like "solve this problem and come back with the solution in a month". There are enough jobs for those people, but working in academia is usually not the right thing for them.

Trying to get a PhD does not express the wish staying in academia. At least in STEM, more then 50% are going to industry or non-academic research.

@usr1234567 Probably depends on the subject. From my experience: In maths, nearly everyone I know wanted to stay in academia when they started the PhD, but at the end, it was different. In engineering many people started a PhD without the intention to go to academia. But leaving the intentions aside, I also think that often a PhD is not really that useful for work outside academia (leaving special areas like chemistry aside).

I'm sure many of us had times during our PhDs when we needed more structured encouragement.  Hopefully this is a short phase of being stuck and she'll come through it with your help.
Some brief daily communication may be a good idea, and in some situations could be delegated to a postdoc; their role may be perceived as more of a supportive one, avoiding adding to the anxiety the student is probably feeling.
Something else I've seen work successfully, is for the student to be expected to make daily progress notes, to be available at the weekly meeting.
While not a perfect tool for this situation, an approach informed by SOFT (successes, opportunities, failures, & threats) reports is simple and could be helpful: What progress have I made? What are the next steps I should be looking into? What has gone wrong? What issues do I think will cause problems?  One line on each of those would be a sensible scale for any daily update, with the expectation of being ready to provide more detail.

Absolutely. Taking time off the student who is overwhelmed and giving them another task to prepare for every day is clearly going to help.....
I would suggest the fact you even asked this question indicates the student may not be the whole problem.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I'm Portuguese and I understood your satiric comment.  And you are correct overloading a student is not the way to go. You still need to clarify that in your answer!

As always it depends on how one asks a student for a daily report. Asking for a report and not anyone else knowing about it, yes it is more than rude, actually, it is unsafe for a professor and for the student.
I could go on here on why it is unsafe, however, I'll skip it and go to the important part, and keep in mind we're now mid-2024!
What is important for a student is that he or she finishes his/her studies successfully. For a professor or scientific research supervisor, the same. So how can a prof. / sc. res. supervisor manages a work culture and environment for that to be possible, for a student to be able to deliver daily and even intraday reports of ongoing works?
It can do it online. In a "neutral", secure, and safe platform, for instance, Github, a dataverse, zenodo. Personally, I give preference to GitHub as it has many functionalities that allow the delivery of written content using markdown language. Nowadays it also supports MathJax for writing mathematical formulae and equations. Finally, GitHub has a built-in document revision that keeps track of any changes made to a document.
There's also the option to use Twitter and LinkedIn, asking a student to publish once a day about work activities. For instance a publication about new content on a page on GitHub. With new photos and videos, etc ...
In the end, when work is done and the course/program/scholarship is completed the student has available to advertise professionally a data repository full of work that can be used to showcase his\her professional skills online to HR recruiters. When using Twitter or Linkedin as a history of records with a timeline, it allows easier navigation by someone interested in learning more about work and skills.
The professor/sci. res. supervisor is able to copy the data repository, on Github is as simple as making a "fork" of it. to use it for his \ her professional needs.

To make it easier to understand what I commented above, I'm sharing here an ongoing open scientific research project that is using Github repositories to deliver near real-time updates of work activities:
https://github.com/aeonSolutions/openScience-Smart-DAQ-to-Upload-Live-Experimental-Data-to-a-Data-Repository/wiki/Validation-of-Experimental-Data-Origins:-A-Swarm-of-DAQ-devices-able-to-Deliver-Unique-Experimental-Data-using-Blockchain‐like-Fingerprint-ID-to-a-Data-Repository

Actually it is less rude to have it in private, given the reasons as described in the question. Having the report in public sounds more like blaming her.

for sure it is private.

I disagree with both and it is simple to understand. The student must come first,, in particular when thinking about his or her professional future.
